# Azure Table Storage PHP Error

Tags: php, azure, azure-table-storage

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
// Load Azure Drivers
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\QueryEntitiesOptions;


// Connection String
$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account_name>;AccountKey=<account_key>==';

// Create table REST proxy.
$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);


$user_input = "Username eq '<user>'";

try {
    $result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities("<table>", $user_input);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    echo "<h1>Error querying, please contact Admin.</h1>";
    die();
}

$entities = $result->getEntities();
foreach($entities as $entity){
    echo $entity;
}
?>
```

I have censored out all the connection and table information. But everything works when I use the demo code. But I want to retrieve the full row. When I execute this I get this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\Models\Entity could not be converted to string
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you are trying to `echo` an object which raised this issue. As the `$entity` in your looping statement is an object, you cannot directly `echo` it.

The [`queryEntities()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Table/TableRestProxy.php#L985) returns [`QueryEntitiesResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesResult.php) object, and then you call [`getEntities()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesResult.php#L88) function which returns [Entity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Table/Models/Entity.php) objects in array.

So you can use functions `$entity->getXXXX()` or `$entity->getPropertyValue({key})` to get the properties in your table storage's entity.

You can refer to [a simple sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/TableSamples.php#L121) for a quick glance.

Comment: I figured out that $entity->getProperty("<property>") will allow me to get the property but is there anyway to list all properties at once without calling them one by one?

Comment: Currently, there is no such functionality

Comment: Alright thank you I managed to use a foreach and parse it into a json array